# Angular2 routing to sibling with children routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-meteor

I am working through the Angular2 documentation on routing and have set up a test app with 3 siblings, with one sibling having three children. I have set up the router but am only able to route to the parent of the children by setting up the "redirectTo" property to redirect to one of the children. If I omit that property I get the following error: "Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'test_landing' .However, I have content that I want to display when routing to the parent and I lose it by the redirect.

```
Here is my router:
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import {MaterialTest} from './materialtest.component';
//parent sibling with children
import { TestLanding } from './testlanding.component';
  import { TestPage1 } from './test1.component';
  import { TestPage2 }   from './test2.component';
  import { TestPage3 } from './test3.component';


const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  { path: 'material_test', component: MaterialTest},
  { path: 'test_landing', component: TestLanding ,
   children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo:'test1', pathMatch: "full"}, //Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'test_landing'
    { path: 'test1',  component: TestPage1 },
    { path: 'test2',  component: TestPage2 },
    { path: 'test3',  component: TestPage3 }
  ]
 }
]

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

I have also read through the excellent documentation here: http://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html, as well as this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/6Mdn7qUblMtktpQyFJAc and thet seem to suggest that I have to set up my router as I did above. Is there are reason for this or have I missed something?

Comment: can you show your router-outlet in your main component html